# AngularJs how to use controller data to change link in factory

Tags: angularjs

I am AngularJs beginner.

How should I change a link in factory inserting data from controller?
Ng-repeat writes all city names I want but it should also write temperature of these cities.

Thank you in advance.

```
var citylink = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+locale+'&units=metric&callback=JSON_CALLBACK' //variable 'locale' should take data from controller;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/291/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick update to get what you want working: http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/292/

It isn't the best way to do it, but should get you started. Essentially you need to run the weather service once for each individual locale. By putting each temp inside your array, you can leverage the same `ng-repeat`